# Cakepdf not showing image for DomPdf

Tags: cakephp, dompdf, cakephp-4.x

I am using [cakepdf](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf) plugin to generate pdf in cakephp application.
I am using below configuration for dompdf

```
Configure::write('CakePdf', [
            // 'engine' => 'CakePdf.WkHtmlToPdf',
            'engine' => 'CakePdf.DomPdf',
            'margin' => [
                'bottom' => 15,
                'left' => 50,
                'right' => 30,
                'top' => 45
            ],
            'orientation' => 'landscape',
            'download' => false,
            'isRemoteEnabled'=> true
            // 'enable-local-file-access' => true
]);
```

I have added `'isRemoteEnabled'=> true`

For display image I have used

```
<img src="<?= WWW_ROOT ?>img/4dx/01/00.png" />
```

I have also tried by

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('4dx/01/00.png', ['fullBase' => true]); ?>
```

Same result no any change found. $this->Html->image this way also not working for WkHtmlToPdf. I am using PHP version 7.4.x

This image perfectly showing if I use WkHtmlToPdf engine, but for dompdf I am not getting image, it's showing not found. Like below image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Engine options must be passed via the `engine` option, eg:

```php
'engine' => [
    'className' => 'CakePdf.DomPdf',
    'options' => [
        'isRemoteEnabled' => true,
    ]
],
```

Also note that the `WWW_ROOT` constant holds is a filesystem path! In order to be able to access the filesystem you must configure the `chroot` option in recent versions of Dompdf!

```php
'engine' => [
    'className' => 'CakePdf.DomPdf',
    'options' => [
        // allow local file access to webroot and Dompdf files
        'chroot' => [
            WWW_ROOT,
            ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'dompdf' . DS . 'dompdf' . DS,
        ],
    ]
],
```

See also

- **https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf/tree/4.1.1#configuration**
- **https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#options**
- **https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#security-restrictions-for-local-files**
- **https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2229**